# 'Not all code paths return a value' using 'try and catch' block

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have the following interfaces:

```
//define a method to create a Stream from a generic source
interface IStream
{
    Stream GetStream();
}
```

and

```
//define a method to deserialize an object from a stream
interface IDeserializer<T>
{
    T GetObject();
}
```

and the two following classes that implement them:

```
//create a new Stream from a URL source
class UrlReader : IStream
{
    private String url;

    public UrlReader(String u)
    { url = u; }

    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//deserialize a JSON object implementing the interface IDeserializer
class JsonDeserializer<T> : IDeserializer<T>
{
    private String json;

    public JsonDeserializer(String j)
    { json = j; }

    public T GetObject()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

I would like to add the try and catch block to both methods to manage exceptions however if I do so not all code paths will return a value. I know a way to resolve this problem is to decalre and initialize the variable to return before the try block. However I cannot initialize a variable of type Stream as this is an abstract class and I cannot initialize a variable of generic type T.
Can you please advise how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to find a concrete implementation of a Stream, such as a `MemoryStream`, create an instance and return it

*or*

return `null` in which case someone else may run into a `NullReferenceException`

*or*

let the exception go though.

Think about it, whether it is a good idea of returning a stream that is empty. Someone will try to read from it and run into other issues.

An exception is not such a bad idea because it leaves the decision of what to do to the user of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `default(T)` and let it return `NULL` (your Stream is a reference type).

Simple example:

```
class test<T>
{
    public T Return()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine ((new test<string>()).Return());
    Console.WriteLine ((new test<int>()).Return());
    Console.WriteLine ((new test<Stream>()).Return());
}
```

THis will output

```
null
0
null
```

`string` and `Stream` are reference types, hence `default(T)` returns NULL.
`int` is a value type with default value zero, hence it'll return 0.

Answer (score 0):

For `Stream`: just return `NULL`. If you don't like `NULL`, just create an empty stream like `MemoryStream` and return it.

For generic type: return default value, which is `default(T)`. For more detail about `default` keyword, please check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You return the obvious thing to return in the case of an exception.

If there is not an obvious thing to return, then this is the wrong place to handle that exception. Either let the exception pass through, or throw a more specific exception.

That certainly would seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

What about dealing ultimately with a memory stream ?

```
public class W : I
    {
        public Stream GetStream()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            try
            {
                var connectStream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://www.google.com");
                if (connectStream != null)
                {
                    connectStream.CopyTo(ms);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return ms;
        }
    }

    public interface I
    {
        Stream GetStream();
    }
```